# Reemplazar mayúsculas por otro carácter

Tags: python

En Python, ¿Como puedo reemplazar los elementos que esté en mayúsculas en una cadena de texto por el valor `$`?

Esto es lo he hecho yo:

```
def reemplazo(string):
    i = 0

    while i < len(string):
        if string[i].isupper():
            string = string.replace(string[i], "$")
        i = i + 1
    return string

# variables

a = raw_input("Ingrese cadena: ")

palabra = reemplazo(a)

print(a)
```

Pero el resultado no es el esperado. Para la cadena: `ViVa`
obtengo: `Viva`.

¿Por qué no funciona?

Comment: Bienvenido Francisco, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y veas [ask]. Se agradece también que acompañes preguntas de este tipo con el código de lo que has intentado. Saludos

Comment: Como comenta Patricio es recomendable que añadas que has intentado, si andas muy perdido mírate [`str.isupper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isupper). Junto a un `for` para recorrer la cadena puedes conseguir lo que quieres.

Answer (score 1):

Por motivos de eficiencia, no conviene usar la función `str.replace()` letra a letra pues cada vez que se ejecuta esa función se crea una nueva cadena y se desecha la anterior. Esto es, si tu cadena original tenía 10 letras mayúsculas, el bucle creará 10 cadenas intermedias (cada una con una mayúscula menos y un dólar más), para luego quedarse tan solo con la última.

Lo idóneo sería poder reemplazar la letra por dólar *en la misma cadena*, sin crear otras nuevas, pero esto no es posible en python porque las cadenas son inmutables.

La alternativa típica consiste en trabajar con listas de caracteres, que sí que permiten modificar sus elementos, para  hacer el procesado letra a letra. Una vez procesada esa lista, se juntan todos sus elementos de nuevo para crear la cadena resultado.

Por ejemplo, podemos examinar letra a letra el contenido de la cadena e ir añadiendo sus letras (o un dólar) a una lista. Finalmente usando `join()` se juntan los elementos de la lista para formar una cadena. Es decir:

```
original= "Esto Es Una PruebA"
lista_resultado = []
for letra in original:
  if letra.isupper():
    lista_resultado.append("$")
  else:
    lista_resultado.append(letra)
cadena_resultado = "".join(lista_resultado)
print(cadena_resultado)
```

El bucle que va añadiendo letras a la cadena puede escribirse de forma más compacta usando lo que python llama *lists comprehensions*, y quedaría así:

```
def dolar_o_letra(caracter):
  if caracter.isupper():
    return "$"
  else:
    return caracter

original= "Esto Es Una PruebA"
lista_resultado = [ dolar_o_letra(c) for c in original ]
cadena_resultado = "".join(lista_resultado)
print(cadena_resultado)
```

## Actualización

En realidad hay muchas formas diferentes de lograr lo que buscas, por lo que a modo de experimento, usando `timeit`, he cronometrado cuánto tarda cada una para tener algún criterio objetivo para elegir una opción. La diferencia de velocidad no es siempre el mejor criterio a seguir, a menos que tu código tenga que ejecutarse millones de veces sobre muchos datos. Si no es el caso, el criterio para seleccionar un método debería ser la legibilidad.

Estas son las opciones consideradas:

- Usar tu implementación original que va modificando la cadena en cada iteración del bucle (que por cierto *sí que funcionaba*, sólo que en tu ejemplo al final imprimes `a`, la cadena original, en lugar de `palabra`, que sería el resultado de la transformación).
- Usar la implementación que yo sugería en mi respuesta, que cambia la cadena por una lista, itera sobre la lista, y luego vuelve a convertir en cadena el resultado.
- Usar una expresión regular que detecte las mayúsculas y las cambie por dólar, en una sola llamada a `re.sub()`
- Y una un tanto esotérica, usar `str.translate()` que es una función python especialmente optimizada para cambiar una letra por otra según una "tabla de traducción". La tabla de traducción asocia cada letra que queremos cambiar por otra a la cual queremos cambiar. Esa tabla debe crearse antes con `str.maketrans()`.

Estas son cuatro funciones que implementan estos cuatro casos para Python 3 (en el orden enumerado antes):

```
import string
import re

def reemplazo_bucle_str(original):
    i = 0
    while i < len(original):
        if original[i].isupper():
            original = original.replace(original[i], "$")
        i = i + 1
    return original

def reemplazo_bucle_list(original):
  lista_resultado = []
  for letra in original:
    if letra.isupper():
      lista_resultado.append("$")
    else:
      lista_resultado.append(letra)
  return "".join(lista_resultado)

def reemplazo_regex(original):
  return re.sub('[A-ZÁÉÍÓÚÜÑ]', '$', original)

def reemplazo_translate(original):
  mayusculas = string.ascii_uppercase + "ÁÉÍÓÚÜÑ"
  conversion = str.maketrans(mayusculas, "$"*len(mayusculas))
  return original.translate(conversion)
```

He probado las cuatro funciones sobre la siguiente cadena:

```
ejemplo = "Esta Cadena contiene UNAS cuantas MaYÚSculas"
```

Y los tiempos requeridos por cada función han sido:

```
reemplazo_bucle_str(ejemplo)        10.20 µs
reemplazo_bucle_list(ejemplo)        6.75 µs 
reemplazo_regex(ejemplo)             2.61 µs
reemplazo_translate(ejemplo)         5.56 µs
```

Vemos que la más eficiente en términos de tiempo de ejecución es la que usa expresiones regulares, que llega a ser casi 5 veces más rápida que la versión original propuesta por el usuario.

La versión con `translate` puede considerarse un experimento fallido, pues aunque es más rápida que la original, es prácticamente igual de veloz que la versión con listas, y tiene en contra que es mucho más difícil de leer y entender.

Answer (score 0):

**Alternativa 1:**

Sencillamente analizas el problema primero armando un **pseudocódigo** que te sirva de bosquejo. Comenzando con el análisis:

1) Observas que necesitas recorrer el **arreglo** (en este caso una cadena de caracteres) pues eso se soluciona con un **bucle bien sea "for" o "while"**. En este caso escogí **while** para dar el ejemplo. El **bucle** se repetira cuantas veces? las "n" cantidad de **caracteres** que contenga la **cadena**. Como hacemos eso en **python**? con la función **len()** que se encarga de contar la cantidad de caracteres que posee la cadena que le pases como parametro.

2) Observas que necesitas encontrar las **mayúsculas**, entonces buscas referencias en internet si existe alguna función que te permita validar cuando un caracter esta en mayúscula. Como en esta referencia web: [Saber si una cadena contiene solo mayúsculas](http://librosweb.es/libro/python/capitulo_6/metodos_de_validacion.html). Que haces con la función? validas si el caracter en cuestión (al que apunta el **indice del bucle** conforme recorre la cadena) es una mayúscula con un **"if"**

Básicamente con ese análisis rapido y sencillo tienes el bosquejo necesario para proceder a armar tu **programa** como en este ejemplo que diseñé el cual hace justamente lo que necesitas:

```
cadena = "Esto Es Un EjempLo"
i=0

def reemplazar_mayusculas(cadena, i):
    while i<len(cadena):
        if cadena[i].isupper():
            cadena= cadena.replace(cadena[i], '$')
        i+=1
    return cadena

print reemplazar_mayusculas(cadena,i)
```

**Alternativa 2:**

Si eres más experimentado con la programación o al menos con **python** en particular entonces puedes crear una solución mas eficiente aprovechando ciertas bondades. Por ejemplo el **módulo re** que hace referencia a **"regex"** en **python** el cual consiste en el manejo de **expresiones regulares** nos optimizará mucho la solución. Te dejo una referencia de el **módulo re** y como construir **expresiones regulares en python**: [aquí](https://platzi.com/blog/expresiones-regulares-python/)

Como en este caso sólo debemos concentrarnos en las **mayúsculas** la expresión regular que necesitamos es muy sencilla: `[A-Z]`. Entonces solucionamos e

```
import re
cadena = "Esto Es Un EjemplO"
expresion = re.compile('[A-Z]')
caracter= "$"

def reemplazar_mayusculas(cadena, expresion, caracter):

    expresion=expresion.sub(caracter, cadena)
    return expresion

print reemplazar_mayusculas(cadena, expresion, caracter)
```

Eso es todo! Un Saludo!